# Does the device that supports USB 3.0 work via computer that supports USB 2.0

Tags: compatibility, usb-2, usb-3

I am planning to buy external hard drive that supports USB 3.0. Will it work with my old notebook that has USB 2.0?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can a USB 3.0 pen drive be used on a USB 2.0 port?](http://superuser.com/questions/270744/can-a-usb-3-0-pen-drive-be-used-on-a-usb-2-0-port)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, USB 3.0 is backwards compatible. However, some new instructions are added to the new 3.0 standard so some functionality might not work. However, most hardware will support USB 2.0 and I won't expect too much problems with an external hard drive.

Reference from [PCWorld](http://www.pcworld.com/article/186566/usb_30_finally_arrives.html):

> The beauty of USB 3.0 is its backward
>   compatibility with USB 2.0; you need a
>   new cable and new host adapter (or,
>   one of the Asus or Gigabyte
>   motherboards that supports USB 3.0) to
>   achieve USB 3.0, but you can still use
>   the device on a USB 2.0 port and
>   achieve typical USB 2.0 performance.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, the devices will work together at USB 2.0 speeds.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your device. A hard drive sould work but obviously not with full speed.