# Can a USB 3.0 pen drive be used on a USB 2.0 port?

Tags: usb, compatibility

I want to buy a USB 3.0 pen drive. But in my pc there is only a USB 2.0 port.

Would a USB 3.0 pen drive work on my pc?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the various types and technologies of USB ports are *generally* designed to be backwards-compatible. However, there is no guarantee that this will be true in all cases.

You can find more information on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Serial_Bus#Compatibility).

> USB 3.0 receptacles are electrically compatible with USB Standard 2.0 device plugs if they physically match. Most combinations will work, but there are a few physical incompatibilities.However, only USB 3.0 Standard-A receptacles can accept USB 3.0 Standard-A device plugs.