# Is USB 3.0 backwards compatible?

Tags: usb, compatibility, usb-3

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can a USB 3.0 pen drive be used on a USB 2.0 port?](https://superuser.com/questions/270744/can-a-usb-3-0-pen-drive-be-used-on-a-usb-2-0-port)

I am really excited about USB 3, especially since it has made its way into the new MacBook Airs and Pros. Since it is much faster than any other interface, I really want to get an USB 3 external drive. However, I am a bit concerned about the backwards compatibility. Is USB 3 backwards compatible? For instance, if I plug a USB 3.0 device into a computer with USB 2, will the drive work?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can a USB 3.0 pen drive be used on a USB 2.0 port?](http://superuser.com/questions/270744/can-a-usb-3-0-pen-drive-be-used-on-a-usb-2-0-port) and [Does the device that supports USB 3.0 work via computer that supports USB 2.0?](http://superuser.com/questions/233753/does-the-device-that-supports-usb-3-0-work-via-computer-that-supports-usb-2-0?rq=1) you might also be interested in [Is there any benefit to plugging a USB 2.0 device into a USB 3.0 port?](http://superuser.com/questions/293189/is-there-any-benefit-to-plugging-a-usb-2-0-device-into-a-usb-3-0-port)

Answer (score 33):

Yes, a USB 3.0 external drive [will work](http://www.techspot.com/guides/235-everything-about-usb-30/) on a USB 2.0 port.
Very broadly, if the path from your drive to the system USB port has one non USB 3.0 component,
the interface will fall back to USB 2.0.

> USB 3.0 Drive ==> USB 3.0 cable ==> USB 3.0 Port on Device

[image]

> **It's backwards compatible**.
> Your existing USB 2.0 gear will work on version 3.0 ports and vice versa. You'll be able to maximize your bandwidth when using a USB 3.0 cable with USB 3.0 devices and ports, otherwise **plugging a 3.0 device into a 2.0 port or a 2.0 device into 3.0 a port will get you standard USB 2.0 data rates.**
>
> Since the new interface has been carefully planned from the start to peacefully co-exist with its predecessor, the connector itself remains mostly the same with the four USB 2.0 contacts in the exact same location as before. Extra pins for the new lanes dedicated to transmit and receive SuperSpeed data are located on the back and only come into contact when mated with a proper USB 3.0 port.

[10 things you should know about USB 2.0 and 3.0](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/10things/10-things-you-should-know-about-usb-20-and-30/1265) <sup>from *December 2009*.</sup>
More details at this [**FAQ**](http://www.everythingusb.com/superspeed-usb.html) and the Wikipedia article on [USB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Serial_Bus#USB_3.0).

Comment: will usb 3.1 work on usb 2.0 ports??

Answer (score 5):

It will work but you will still be limited to USB 2.0 transfer rates. To get the increase speed you would also need a USB 3.0 port in your computer.

Comment: Which are readily available and make backup to a USB 3.0 external drive much quicker.