# Is it possible to use USB 3.0 Pendrive into my Laptop's USB 2.0 Port?

Tags: windows, usb-flash-drive, usb-3, usb-2

Currently I am having USB 2.0 port Laptop. I am in the plan to buy USB 3.0 Pendrive/External Hard Disk. Whether USB 3.0 pendrive/ext HDD will support USB 2.0 Laptop's port? Or it will have problem to use?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does the device that supports USB 3.0 work via computer that supports USB 2.0](http://superuser.com/questions/233753/does-the-device-that-supports-usb-3-0-work-via-computer-that-supports-usb-2-0), [Can a USB 3.0 pen drive be used on a USB 2.0 port?](http://superuser.com/questions/270744/can-a-usb-3-0-pen-drive-be-used-on-a-usb-2-0-port), [Is USB 3.0 backwards compatible?](http://superuser.com/questions/437687/is-usb-3-0-backwards-compatible?rq=1)

Comment: @techie007 i didnt get this link thats why i asked here.

Answer (score 1):

USB is backwards compatible so you can use USB 3.0 device in an USB 2.0 port, but the device will only run at USB 2.0 speed.

Comment: Assuming it doesn't draw more than 500mA.  That's a safe assumption for a flash drive, but maybe not for a USB 3.0 external hard drive.